# Js regex how to determine invalid if duplicate word is present

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-lookarounds

I am wondering how this can be done using js regex. I have the following strings.

1. `"{{abc-xyz}} #ffffff   mnop"`
2. `"{{abc-xyz}} #5dffff   #5dffff mnop"`

I need javascript regex that determines string #1) as valid and #2) as invalid. #2 has the repeated word #5dffff.

I've tried `{{[a-zA-Z0-9\s&#_-]+}}\B(\#[a-z]+)\s+[\w\s]+`.

Comment: any attempts from your side.

Comment: Can you be more specific as to what can/can't be repeated? Please show some examples. And most importantly, what have you tried so far?

Comment: i spent several hours on it since i am pretty new to this but this is what i have so far. {{[a-zA-Z0-9\s&#_-]+}}\B(\#[a-z]+)\s+[\w\s]+

Comment: @BusyBees Always add your attempts to solve problem in question.

Comment: sure. I guess this has to do something with the grouping.

Answer (score 1):

Try this `Regex`

```
(\b\S+\b)(?=.*\1)
```

[Regex Link](https://regex101.com/r/eR6oI2/1)

Comment: I guess this is partially working to my need (it's failing on invalid ones which i can use to negate) except it won't validate curley braces {{abc-xyz}}. How would i consider doing this?

Comment: @AnantDabhi Adjusted slightly to `/(.*\s)(?=.*\1)/` `!str.match(/(.*\s)(?=.*\1)/).join("").trim().length;`

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand what you're trying to achieve.
Try this: `"{{[A-Za-z-]*}}\s(#[a-zA-Z0-9]+)\s*\1\s*[a-z]*"`

This expression will match your string #2. If that matches you can decide your string is invalid, I hope this helps to set you on the right path and to research RegEx further.

Comment: But this will also not match "[[abc-xyz]] #ffffff    abcd" which I guess will be an issue if we use this negation.

Comment: @BusyBees you have two strings in which case Regex will either pass or fail. If you look for passing regex then you can compare this to zero matches found. If you look for failing result (like #2) then in your IF statement check for matches found with what I provided.

Answer (score 0):

> need javascript regex that determines string #1) as valid and #2) as
>   invalid. #2 has the repeated word #5dffff.

Try using `String.prototype.split()` with `RegExp` `/\s+/` to remove space characters , `Array.prototype.every()` , `.indexOf()` , `.lastIndexOf()`

```js
var str1 = "{{abc-xyz}} #ffffff   mnop";

var str2 = "{{abc-xyz}} #5dffff   #5dffff mnop";

var norepeat = function norepeat(str) {
  return str.split(/\s+/).every(function(a) {
    return str.lastIndexOf(a) === str.indexOf(a)
  })
}

var res1 = norepeat(str1);

var res2 = norepeat(str2);

console.log(res1, res2)
```

Comment: Liked the approach but i prefer regex solution. Can't go with this.